# Craft CMS with other Yii2 Applications

Tags: apache, yii2, content-management-system, craftcms

I'm facing a few issues with server configuration it seems.

I have Craft CMS installed and I'm also running few Yii2 applications on subfolders of the root.

Basically my server is structured as follows:

- Craft/
- public_html/

  - .htaccess
  - index.php (craft)
  - css/ (craft)
  - images/ (craft)
  - yii2-app-1/
  - yii2-app-2/

Going to http://www.test.com/ - takes me to the main website running Craft
Going to http://www.test.com/yii2-app-1/ - takes me to the yii2 app home page however after few clicks it either throws a 404 or 503 error for some reason.

Any clue why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have redefined the access routing  you should use

```
 http://www.test.com/yii2-app-1/web/index.php
```

for accessing to the application